# XSLT: Sorted path trace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input:

```
<articles>
  <item name="B">
    <item name="Bb">
      <item name="Bbb"/>
      <item name="Abb"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Ab">
      <item name="Bab"/>
      <item name="Aab"/>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item name="A">
    <item name="Ba">
      <item name="Bba"/>
      <item name="Aba"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Aa">
      <item name="Baa"/>
      <item name="Aaa"/>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item name="D"/>
  <item name="C">
    <item name="Ac"/>
  </item>
</articles>
```

And need the following output:

```
A-Aa-Aaa
A-Aa-Baa
A-Ba-Aba
A-Ba-BBa
B-Ab-Aab
B-Ab-Bab
B-Bb-Abb
B-Bb-Bbb
C-Ac
D
```

That is, every path shall be made explicit and be sorted on every level. I have the following XSLT, which produces the paths, but I cannot figure out the sorting, except for the first level.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="articles">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//item[not(item)]">
      <xsl:sort select="ancestor-or-self::item[parent::articles]/@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::item">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(item)">
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>-</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm afraid my current approach is a dead end. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**Do note, that the XSLT 2.0 solution (part II) is much shorter and simpler**.

---

**I. Here is a simple, 2-pass solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*">
   <xsl:sort/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item[not(item)]">
     <x>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::item">
       <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">-</xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </x>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<articles>
  <item name="B">
    <item name="Bb">
      <item name="Bbb"/>
      <item name="Abb"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Ab">
      <item name="Bab"/>
      <item name="Aab"/>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item name="A">
    <item name="Ba">
      <item name="Bba"/>
      <item name="Aba"/>
    </item>
    <item name="Aa">
      <item name="Baa"/>
      <item name="Aaa"/>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item name="D"/>
  <item name="C">
    <item name="Ac"/>
  </item>
</articles>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
A-Aa-Aaa
A-Aa-Baa
A-Ba-Aba
A-Ba-Bba
B-Ab-Aab
B-Ab-Bab
B-Bb-Abb
B-Bb-Bbb
C-Ac
D
```

**Do note**: This is a generic solution that works correctly with *any* nestedness of `item` elements.

**Explanation**:

1. We perform a two-pass transformation.
2. The result of the first pass is:

   ```
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">B-Bb-Bbb</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">B-Bb-Abb</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">B-Ab-Bab</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">B-Ab-Aab</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">A-Ba-Bba</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">A-Ba-Aba</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">A-Aa-Baa</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">A-Aa-Aaa</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">D</x>
   <x xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">C-Ac</x>
   ```
3. The processing of the first pass uses a single template that matches only the *leaf* `item` elements. For each leaf `item` element its full, dash-delimited path is output as the contents of an element named `x`.
4. The second pass simply sorts the results of the first pass.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="//item[not(item)]"
     group-by="string-join(ancestor-or-self::item/@name, '-')">
      <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key(), '&#xA;'"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but the following does it for a depth of 3 items, and would require additional sorts for each additional level. I'm sure that a guru will be able to do this more generically :)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="articles">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//item[not(item)]">
            <xsl:sort select="ancestor-or-self::item[parent::articles]/@name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ancestor-or-self::item[parent::item[parent::articles]]/@name"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ancestor-or-self::item[parent::item[parent::item[parent::articles]]]/@name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::item">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(item)">
                    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>-</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```